# Prove $f'$ is continuous at $x_0$

Tags: calculus, functions

Let $f$ such that $f'$ defined at $x_0$ and $\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to x_0} f'(x)$ exists. Show that $f'$ is continuous at $x_0$.

Well, I was guided to use L'Hospital's rule for $f'(x)$. Therefore, we have:

$$f'(x_0) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} \frac{{f(x) - f({x_0})}}{{x - {x_0}}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} \frac{{\left( {f(x) - f({x_0})} \right)'}}{{(x - {x_0})'}} = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to {x_0}} f'(x) - f'({x_0})
$$

I'm stuck at that point but I know I'm one step close to the solution.

Comment: If $f'(x_0)$ exists, the function is continuous at $x_0$ without any hypothesis on $\lim_{x\to x_0}f'(x)$. Maybe you reported wrongly the problem.

Comment: @egreg, corrected. it's $f'$ (not $f$).

Comment: Well, at least $f'$ should exist in a neighborhood of $x_0$, not only at $x_0$.

Comment: $(f(x_0))'=0$. (Note $f(x_0)$ is a constant.)

Comment: Got it @DavidMitra, Thanks for the observation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $f'$ exists in a neighborhood of $x_0$, you can surely apply l'Hôpital's theorem:
$$
f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}
\overset{(\mathrm{H})}{=}
\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}
$$

Answer (score 2):

You should use the machine behind the l'Hopital rule, the extended mean value theorem. Or here just the mean value theorem.

$$\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_1)$$

for some $x_1$ between $x_0$ and $x$. Then when $x\to x_0$ it also forces $x_1\to x_0$.